# "Modifier and Type" in a Javadoc using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I am using Netbeans to create and finalize my Java app. I am doing my javadoc's now but have an issue. See how the modifier and type column spells out the type completely? Even java.lang.String is completely spelled out. In API's I see the type is not spelled out like that.

Is there some sort of setting I am missing in Netbeans to keep that from happening? It really makes the document cluttered when reading it.

[image: Typing in a Javadoc using Netbeans]

Comment: Could you show us the source that generated this Javadoc?

Comment: It's a built in function that is already present in netbeans when installed. I can show you the HTML, but WYSIWYG.

Comment: Oh, ok. I don't know how this built in function works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fully qualified name a class is used whenever the Javadoc tool is unable to find the source or an existing Javadoc for this class. Here you will need to specify where to find the JDK's Javadoc, using the `-link`option of the javadoc tool. For instance, to include Java 8 API documentation, you would use `-link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api`

I encourage you to read the [related documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javadocoptions) for more details and possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is 100% correct. I would just like to add the way this can be done on an Ant Project through Netbeans, as I also needed it and did not find it anywhere.

To do that on an Ant project edit the file **project.properties** under **nbproject** directory in the root of your project. (To do it through Netbeans  go to **Files** tab on the right, expand **nbproject** and open (double click) **project.properties**) Find and edit `javadoc.additionalparam=` by placing the parameter next to "=".
e.g.: `javadoc.additionalparam=-link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api`

edit: Another way to add additional javadoc parameters is by going to Project Properties -> 
Build -> Documenting and add the additional parameter next to `Additional Javadoc Options`